# Insert`tr` at beginning of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to move the user selected `tr` to the beginning of the table:

```
 $(this).closest('tr').insertBefore($('#TableBody').find('tr:first'));
```

I dont know why it wont work! In my example http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5207/ the table works like a dropdown. If the user then selects one option by clicking on `Auswählen` this `tr` should be inserted as first `tr` in the table!

Thanks for your help

Comment: just for the record: never write `{class: `, write `{"class": ` because `class` is an reserved variable in internet explorer

Comment: Refer this one-http://jsfiddle.net/Dpn2Z/

Comment: Try to put the code that you mentioned above inside cells click event directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **[prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** or can try **[prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)**

**by prepend()**

```
$('#TableBody').prepend($(this).closest('tr'));
```

by **prependTo()**

```
 $(this).closest('tr').prependTo($('#TableBody'));
```

Comment: this is due to your $(this).closest("tr") not working properly on your code

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
$('#TableBody').prepend($(this).closest('tr'));
```